# HIbernate: Not all Named parameters have been set

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am setting a native query in jpa but it did not running as expected and giving me exception
      This is my query:

```
    l_query = "SELECT creationdate AS " + m_dateFrom.getValue(); 
                l_query += "AND creationdate AS"  + m_dateTo.getValue(); 
                l_query += "from tablename";

    Error i am getting is:

     org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [20:53] [SELECT creationdate AS Tue Mar 01 10:20:53 IST 2016AND creationdate ASThu Apr 07 10:20:53 IST 2016from tablename]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing some blank spaces before the key words AND and FROM in lines 2 an 3, and after the key word AS on line 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your query, mainly due to it not being valid SQL. The named parameters error is shown because the date value is not in inside quotes, so it is parsing it and getting confused due to the semi colons `:`.
The easiest way to fix this is to use quotes `'` for the values you are concatenating and cast them to `DATE` (which I assume is what you want), replace the `AND` with a comma `,` and add spaces between the string concatenation.

Comment: can you provide example

Answer (score 0):

Your l_query is wrong. You missed spaces in different parts of your query. The QueryException shows your the wrong sql.

You mentioned that you use `jpa` in your project. **Why do you not use it?**

For me it looks like you do not need a simple `native query` in this case. Use a `jpql query` instead.

Your Query is also a big problem for sql injection because you give the attribute value directly in your query. Use parameters instead.

For example your code can be build on this sample code:

```
public List findWithName(String name) {
    return em.createQuery(
        "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName")
        .setParameter("custName", name)
        .getResultList();
}
```

[Here are some examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html)

**EDIT:**

```
StringBuilder l_query = new StringBuilder("SELECT t.creationdate AS '" + m_dateFrom.getValue()); 
l_query.append("', t.creationdate AS '"  + m_dateTo.getValue()); 
l_query.append("' from tablename t").toString();
```

Comment: I am using native query not named

Comment: @tusharsharma I know. But why? You are using jpa in your project. For me just complex queries should be native. But this is your decission.

Comment: @tusharsharma I updated my answer. check if its fits your needs